# PHPInfo / Valet - Two different PHP versions

Tags: php, laravel, valet

OK so I am experiencing something quite odd. My `phpinfo()` shows one version while `php -v` shows another.

I am running locally on a MacBook Air (Mojave), with **Laravel** and **Valet**.

`phpinfo()`:

```
PHP Version 7.2.13

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/etc/php/7.2
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d
```

While in my terminal, it shows:

`php -v`

```
PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 11:00:11) ( NTS )
```

Now, if I do a `which php` I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

In my `~/.bash-profile`, I have this:

`export "PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

I have tried to:

- Restart Nginx
- Restart Valet
- Unlink PHP@7.2 and link PHP@7.3with Homebrew:

  Olivers-MacBook-Air:~ oliverbusk$ brew unlink php@7.2
  Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2

How can I get my actual valet site to use **php@7.3**?

Comment: Use [php switcher](https://github.com/philcook/brew-php-switcher). This helps you to switch php correctly and restart valet.

Comment: `rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock; valet restart;` solved it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something so basic as rebooting my Macbook solved this issue. Once rebooted, the correct version `7.3` showed in my `phpinfo();`

Comment: rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock; valet restart; solved it for me

Comment: @Chk I got a 'Bad gateway' on the Valet site after this command. `valet install` solved it for me.

Answer (score 46):

Below simple fix worked for me.

```
rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
valet restart
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me - Thanks @Chk!

Comment: Works good but I seem to need to repeat this every now and then (perhaps after restarting my computer), is there a permanent solution?

Comment: worked on ubuntu too, just a different path, at least on my machine, `rm ~/.valet/valet.sock`

Comment: Not sure why I lose this configuration after restarting and have to do it again and again, anyone else?

Comment: Would love to know how to fix this so it doesn't keep happening.

Comment: This should be added into the valet library as restart command as well

Comment: Removing the valet sock resulted in a 502 Bad Gateway after restart.

Comment: @AlxVallejo I think you will need to run `valet install` in this case, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837655/laravel-valet-502-bad-gate-way-nginx-1-15-7

Answer (score 6):

In my case it worked after forcing the specific PHP version:

```
valet use php@7.4 --force
```

Answer (score 5):

Good news, please upgrade to latest valet version, you can easily switch php version.
Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet

> PHP Versions
>
> Valet allows you to switch PHP versions using the valet use php@version command. Valet will install the specified PHP version via Brew if it is not already installed:

```
valet use php@7.2

valet use php   //without any specification, it will be using latest version
```

Answer (score 3):

From MacBook pro (Mojave), with Laravel and Valet:

```
valet use php@7.2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, eve if it is ok, try to explain your answer a little bit. If it is a new point of view, show Pros and Cons. I already edit your answer, but the official language on SO is english, there is another SO on Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to effectively change the version of php on my machine I use the following script:

Add to your user's .bash_profile
Then use the following command to switch

switch-php7.x

```
switch-php() {
  valet stop
  brew unlink php@7.2 php@7.3 php@7.4
  brew link --force --overwrite php@$1
  brew services restart php@$1
  composer global update
  rm -f ~/.config/valet/valet.sock
  valet install
}
```

https://gist.github.com/r1tt3r/e0f199eb274d5ff186b73956af594316

Answer (score 3):

I am running [linux valet](https://cpriego.github.io/valet-linux/) on **Ubuntu 20.04** , The following command works for me

```sh
valet use 8.0
```

Here, 8.0 refers to the php version.

Comment: you save my day . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically the php valet uses and the one used by your macbook is different.
But as already mentioned by @Shiro and @Israel Alexis Palma Quezada, in newer versions `valet use php73` would solve your problem.
If it's not working, try running `composer global update` to update your global packages, thus updating valet

To update the mac php version, execute the following lines:

```
export PATH="your/path/to/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="your/path/to/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"
```

or simply add these two lines to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Don't forget to run `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bash_profile` or whatever file you chose to edit.

Comment: `composer global update` did it!

Answer (score 2):

NB: Tested this solution on **Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop**

If you are using [Valet Linux Plus](https://valetlinux.plus/)(Has more features than Valet Linux) Just do `valet use {your PHP version} --update-cli`.  For instance to use php8.0 just run:

```
valet use 8.0 --update-cli
```

This will update both php-fpm version plus php-cli version too.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 18.

At first I changed the PHP version:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php7.2
$ sudo a2enmod php7.3
$ sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/7.3
```

But valet was still showing the wrong PHP version. Rebooting did not work. In fact, `phpinfo()` was displaying PHP 7.1.

After run `ps -aux | grep php` I noticed few instances of `php-fpm` (5.6, 7.1 and 7.2) running.

I stopped them

```
$ sudo service php5.6-fpm stop
$ sudo service php7.1-fpm stop
$ sudo service php7.2-fpm stop
```

Then started 7.3

```
$ sudo service php7.3-fpm start
```

And now my `phpinfo()` display the correct version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem while using valet plus today. When I switched PHP versions it was showing the previous one in my browser but the correct one in my terminal. Looking at the my brew services list:

```
brew services list
```

It showed that one of the valet-php services (valet-php@7.2) was not in the service list but somehow my valet was able to switch to it. Valet didn't install this PHP properly and that's what was causing the issue. I did the following to uninstall that PHP and reinstall it with brew.

```
brew uninstall valet-php@7.2
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/valet-php@7.2/7.2.34_1
brew install valet-php@7.2
```

The PHP version that was once not showing in the brew services list now showed and I was able to "stop" that php version's service:

```
brew services stop valet-php@7.2
```

which made everything work properly again without a restart.