# Laravel Valet 502 Bad Gate Way nginx/1.15.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway on my Laravel projects running Laravel valet.

I have tried many of the solutions online and with no success. *i.e.* https://gist.github.com/adamwathan/6ea40e90a804ea2b3f9f24146d86ad7f

At the moment the error I see is 502 bad gateway and an error in my command line when running valet install is an error when it gets to the updating PHP configuration. It gives the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php-fpm.d/www.conf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/username/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Filesystem.php on line 112

Warning: file_get_contents(/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php-fpm.d/www.conf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/username/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Filesystem.php on line 125
```

Has anybody had similar issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same symptoms after updating to php 7.3 and then installing a new Laravel project.

It appears that brew install php73 doesn't install php-fpm

Solution is to uninstall php

```
brew uninstall php73 
brew uninstall php72
brew uninstall php71 ... whatever versions you have
brew uninstall --force php
```

Now reinstall php

```
brew install php --build-from-source
```

I encountered permission errors `mkdir: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php-fpm.d: Permission denied` so `sudo chown -R: <yourusercode> /usr/local/etc/php` fixed that and then `brew install php --build-from-source` again. Once it builds php 7.3 successfully reinstall valet:

```
valet install
```

Comment: This is correct, however, we just installed php@7.2 instead and it worked.

Comment: If you don't want to go to an older version, 7.4 also does the trick!

Answer (score 83):

If you're anyone like me who're seeing `502 Bad Gateway` while using [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet) after updating it `composer global update` to the latest version, you most probably forgot to run `valet install` command. Laravel Valet requires *(in most cases)* to run `valet install` command after updating to the latest version.

Comment: This is the actual answer to the user's question above and is a much better first step in diagnosing this problem than the accepted answer, which works because of the last step in the process.

Answer (score 43):

in most cases running `valet install` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

None of the above answers worked for me, but found the solution here: https://janostlund.com/2019-06-20/502-bad-gateway-laravel-valet

`~/.config/valet/Log/nginx-error.log` shows:

```
[error] 17423#0: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream [...]
```

Solved by adding two lines to `http` in  `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
  fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  
  //...
}
```

and then running `valet restart`

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by doing:

```
php -v
```

> PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2021 09:07:02) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

followed by:

```
valet use php@8.0 --force
```

> Unlinking current version: php
> Linking new version: php@8.0
> Updating PHP configuration...
> Restarting php...
> Restarting nginx...
> Valet is now using php@8.0.

Valet seemed to be confused over which PHP it was using.

Comment: This was my issue. I have two PHP versions installed and I had to tell it to use 8.2

Answer (score 2):

Well, normally "valet install" solves the issue but for me it was different.
For my case, I was using valet isolate for a different project with different PHP versions. So, I have to do the binding process again.

I did,

1. valet install
2. valet isolate php@7.1 (Here you have to use the selected version)

this solves the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks you SOOOOOOOOOOOOO much. I would never have found this by trial and error. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I reinstalled different version of `php`. I just run

```
valet install
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: God forbid you do this on a MacBook with tons of sites, I have to fingerprint like 154 https projects 

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with Laravel 8. Both Valet and Expose seemed to work, but the webpage always gave a 502 response.

The solution I found when I updated composer and tried to reinstall Valet was that Valet didn't know which version of php to use.

To fix this, use the following command to tell valet which version of php to use.

```
valet use php@7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
brew services start php
```

If it didn’t work, try to reinstall php from source

```
brew uninstall php
brew install php --build-from-source
valet install
```

Source: [laravel/valet github issues](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/717#issuecomment-458314752)

Answer (score 1):

If the `valet restart` or `valet install` didn't work, try to change the PHP version.

```
valet use php@7.4
```

Or

```
valet isolate php@7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `composer global update`
2. Run `valet install`
3. Run `valet restart`

The last step isn’t always necessary but I’ve found there are times when I’ve had to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by upgrading mariadb. `brew upgrade mariadb`

Answer (score 0):

Following the config above, but put it in the file.

`~/.valet/Nginx/all.conf`

```
  fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

This did catch on all the sites "Im use Valet plus"

Answer (score 0):

My nginx-error.log file was full of messages like this

*3 connect() to unix:/home/oakbox/.valet/valet.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1

It took me too long to figure out that php-fpm was running, but that Nginx could not 'see' that socket. Look in your Nginx configuration file for the line that starts with

```
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/oakbox/.valet/valet.sock;
```

And then look to see if that socket actually exists. In my setup, an update of my system moved my default PHP installation from version 8.1 to 8.2. The actual socket file was renamed from valet.sock to valet82.sock.

I edited my Nginx configuration files to point to the real location of the socket

```
        fastcgi_pass unix:/home/oakbox/.valet/valet82.sock;
```

A restart of Nginx and my 502 Bad Gateway went away.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, I found a fix from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/valeryan/valet-wsl/issues/18). Apparently, my Valet services got messed up when I ran `valet use` command. 502 Bad Gateway was everywhere!

Things I tried:

- `valet uninstall`
- `valet install`
- Unlinked and re-linked the site folder.

Here's what worked:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm
```

According to the GitHub issue, `valet use` messes up the file rights of the services and you need to re-assign the right permissions again. Hopefully I saved anyone looking at this thread some hours of reconfiguring Valet from scratch. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

This is the definite solution:

- Run `valet status` to check the status of all Valet services. Normally they should all have status "Yes", except this one `Is linked PHP (php@<version>) running as root?`
- Run `valet use php@<version>`, make sure you have that php version already installed.
- Happy coding.